# Scarlett 2i2 & Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: sound, alsa, external-soundcard

I recently updated to Ubuntu 16.04, and am having some issues with my Focusrite Scarlett 2i2. It is not shown on System Settings/Audio, but Alsamixer shows it, even if it says "This sound device does not have any control". It seems quite strange since it worked flawlessly on Ubuntu 15.10. Anyway, here's the output for `sudo aplay -l`

```
scheda 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], dispositivo 0: 92HD81B1X5 Analog [92HD81B1X5 Analog]
Sottoperiferiche: 1/1
Sottoperiferica #0: subdevice #0
scheda 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], dispositivo 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
Sottoperiferiche: 1/1
Sottoperiferica #0: subdevice #0
```

I know, my system lanuage is not English but I think you may be able to understand either way.
And here's the output for `lsusb`

```
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 1235:8006 Focusrite-Novation Focusrite    Scarlett 2i2
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 5986:02ac Acer, Inc 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I tried using Qjackctl, but it seems it isn't helping. Anyone has any idea?

Comment: It seems it needs jackd, look http://dragly.org/2014/01/12/focusrite-scarlett-2i2-flawlessly-working-on-ubuntu-with-jack/

Comment: In the end I reinstalled 15.10, and the very moment I plugged my external sound card in, it worked flawlessly. I guess I'll wait a while, then give 16.04 another chance. I'll try looking into jackd.